# Unity 4.3 Play animation on hit

Tags: animation, controller, sprite, collision, hit

I'm currently building a ***2d platformer*** and encountered a few problems.

My player has a script so that when the player hits a cube with a rigid body, the cube can be pushed. When the character pushes the object, the regular walking animation is displayed.

I want to play the pushing animation at that moment but cant seem to fix it. I read a lot of topics on the internet about the difference between unity new ***Animator editor*** and the older versions.

Is there a simple way to trigger the animation on hit, and how do I have to add it in the Animator? Also with witch states should it be connected?

Answer (score 0):

Found it on google, maybe it will help

```
http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/2d-overview
```

He uses a Layer for the animation of the cannon so he animates regardless of the body animation.